# Pytorch Lightning checkpoint does not have 'model' attribute to load in to nn.Module contrary to docs

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am training a model using pytorch lightning and using the ModelCheckpoint callback to save checkpoints:

```
class PLModule(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, model: TestModel, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
    ...

pytorch_model = TestModel()
pl_model = PLModule(pytorch_model, learning_rate, loss_function)

trainer = Trainer(
    accelerator="auto",
    devices="auto",
    strategy="auto",
    logger=TensorBoardLogger("./logs", name="", version=""),
    max_epochs=10,
    callbacks=[
        ModelCheckpoint(monitor="loss/val",mode="min"),
        EarlyStopping(monitor="loss/val", mode="min", patience=5),
        ],
    )
trainer.fit(pl_model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader)
```

I now want to load just the Pytorch nn.Module `TestModel()` to use for inference in a separate module, following the documentation under **nn.Module from checkpoint** here: https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/common/checkpointing_basic.html#nn-module-from-checkpoint

```
checkpoint = torch.load('path_to_checkpoint')
model_weights = checkpoint['model']
inference_model = TestModel()
inference_model.load_state_dict(model_weights)
```

However, the checkpoint has no *model* key??

```
print(checkpoint.keys())
--> dict_keys(['epoch', 'global_step', 'pytorch-lightning_version', 'state_dict', 'loops', 'callbacks', 'optimizer_states', 'lr_schedulers'])
```

It only has a *state_dict*, which does contain the weights I'm after, but the keys are `model.conv1.weight` or `model.conv1.bias` instead of `conv1.weight` or `conv1.bias` so I can't load these into my model. I have to instantiate the whole `PLModule`:

```
model = TestModel()
pl_model = PLModule.load_from_checkpoint('path_to_checkpoint', model=model, *args, **kwargs)
model = pl_model.model
```

which seems totally unnecessary, as I've now got to also load all the optimizer parameters etc, when all I want to do is a forwards pass through the model.

Have I done something wrong with the checkpointing (more likely) or is there an issue in the documentation (less likely but not impossible)?

N.B I'm using pytorch-lightning v2.1.3

N.B.2 I would prefer to keep the instantiation of all the objects outside of the `__init__` function of `PLModule` - I'm running experiments with different models and different loss functions so being able to inject these into the `PLModule` is quite important

Thank you!